# fix bootstrap daterangepicker not displaying properly on bootstrap 3.3.7

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, daterangepicker

I am trying to use bootstrap date-rangepicker 3.0.5 for date selections on **Bootstrap 3.3.7**, and the display is like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/gL2Eq.jpg

My code for this is :

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/3.0.5/daterangepicker.min.css" integrity="sha256-VVbO1uqtov1mU6f9qu/q+MfDmrqTfoba0rAE07szS20=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class='input-group date' id='picker'>
</body>
 <script src="/javascripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha256-4iQZ6BVL4qNKlQ27TExEhBN1HFPvAvAMbFavKKosSWQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/3.0.5/daterangepicker.min.js" integrity="sha256-zI6VVO07NPmVW11q3RQE42YbRmJIkkunrcQ9LEYxJsQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
  // $('#picker').daterangepicker({});
  $('#picker').daterangepicker({
    opens:'left',1  
    timePicker:true,
    ranges   : {
      'Today'       : [moment(), moment()],
      'Yesterday'   : [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
      'Last 7 Days' : [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
      'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
      'This Month'  : [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
      'Last Month'  : [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
    },
    startDate: moment().subtract(29, 'days'),
    endDate  : moment()
  },
  function (start, end) {
    $('#daterange-btn span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'))
  });


</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an input for the result, and you can add a calendar icon next to the input field. Also, remove the "1" after `opens:'left'`.

```js
$('#picker').daterangepicker({
    opens: 'left',
    timePicker: true,
    ranges: {
      'Today': [moment(), moment()],
      'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
      'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
      'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
      'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
      'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
    },
    startDate: moment().subtract(29, 'days'),
    endDate: moment()
  },
  function(start, end) {
    $('input').val(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'))
  });
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/3.0.5/daterangepicker.min.css" integrity="sha256-VVbO1uqtov1mU6f9qu/q+MfDmrqTfoba0rAE07szS20=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" id='picker'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha256-4iQZ6BVL4qNKlQ27TExEhBN1HFPvAvAMbFavKKosSWQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/3.0.5/daterangepicker.min.js" integrity="sha256-zI6VVO07NPmVW11q3RQE42YbRmJIkkunrcQ9LEYxJsQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```